# Build errors stemming from Entity change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-6

Okay so I just found out I need to downgrade my solution to .NET 4.0.  To do this, I upgraded to Entity Framework 6.0 (which is supposed to be .NET 4.0 compatible) and converted all my projects to target the 4.0 framework.  When trying to build my data project, the EDMX has several errors.  I am unable to open it normally but I can modify the XML data.  Here is the error:

```
The type or namespace name "TABLENAME" could not be found.
```

I get a bunch of these for several (but not all) tables in my SQL database.  Normally, I would do a database update but that does not appear possible here since I can't open the file normally.  Additionally, enumerated types that have been defined in the edmx are throwing this error:

```
The element 'Schema' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm' has invalid child element 'EnumType' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm'.  List of possible elements expected: 'Using, Association, CopmlexType, EntityType, Function, EntityContainer' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm' as well as any element in namespace '##other'.
```

The XML generating this issue:

```
<EnumType Name="CustomEnum" />
    <Member Name="Enum1">
    <Member Name="Enum2" />
    ...
    <Member Name="Enum10" />
</EnumType>
```

I was not the creator of this EDMX file but these enums are essential to the project.

Comment: Did you use VisualStudio 2012 without EF6 tooling installed to downgrade your project? If you did this it would change namespaces in edmx to v2 and v2 edmx did not support enums. EF6 tooling will not downgrade the edmx to v2 if the project is retargeted to .NET Framework 4. You can get EF6 tooling from here:http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762 . Also take a look at my blog post on EF6 tooling: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/11/10/what-changed-in-the-ef-tooling-in-visual-studio-2013-and-visual-studio-2012-out-of-band/

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Entity Framework 4.0 and prior and EF 4.1 and up is huge.  The system was moved from 'objectcontext' to 'dbcontext'.  If you are just looking to make your solution run and not upgrade to the latest I would recommend deleting all of the .tt files, turning the generation back on for the edmx and just using base EF 4.0.

If you however want to move to the new 6.0 dbcontext paradigm, you may be in for a lot of work redesigning several classes and how they interact with EF.

Comment: That's not true. You can use both ObjectContext and DbContext in EF6, EF5 and EF4 (EF4 and EF5 required installing EntityFramewwork NuGet package while EF6 is only NuGet and does not rely on System.Data.Entity.dll). In fact EF4.x and EF5 are built on top of System.Data.Entity.dll.

Comment: We were using Entity 5.0 previously, not 4.0, I was just trying to downgrade the .NET framework to 4.0.

Comment: If you used enums it won't work. Enums (and a couple of other things) were not supported in EF4. If you really need to run on .NET Framework 4 I would recommend using EF6 which is a superset of EF5. You may also want to check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/upgradeEF6

Comment: Pawel, you can push a car to your destination too but I wouldn't say its a good idea.  DbContext is for EF 4.1 and up.